# Having trouble saving data to an index typed variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a couple interfaces to shape my data which looks like this

```
export interface BindingItem{ [property:string] : BehaviorSubject<string>; }

export interface BindingObject{ [library:string] : BindingItem; }
```

I have a variable in my service file of type `BindingObject` and I'm trying to populate it with this function

```
private createBindingData(library:string, property:string, setting:string){
    this.BindingData[library][property]= new BehaviorSubject(setting);
}
```

I get an error in the console indicating the value being passed in as the `property` argument can't be assigned to `undefined` in reference to the value entered as the `library` argument.

The variable I'm targeting is initiated as an empty object like this.

```
private BindingData: BindingObject = {};
```

How do I need to go about setting the data in an object shaped like this?

Answer (score 0):

ok I just figured out that I need to define the `library` as an empty object first then set the property as follows

```
private createBindingLibrary(library: string){
    this.BindingData[library] = {};
}

private createBindingProperty(library: string, property: string, setting: string){
    this.BindingData[library][property] = new BehaviorSubject(setting);
}
```